# Display zoomed-out canvas on screen but download full-size canvas with `toDataURL`

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

In my web application, I have a canvas with a download button that will download the current canvas as a PNG using `.toDataURL`.

Let's say my full-size canvas is 100px by 100px

I would like to display the canvas on the web page at a scaled-down scale (let's say 50%) but I would like the download to download the full-scale image. I am stuck on how to achieve this. Right now I am scaling down the whole canvas (both the width and height of the canvas element as well as using fabricCanvas's setZoom function to scale the image for display, but this means that `toDataURL` generates a zoomed-out image for download.

Ideally I would like the canvas to internally be rendered at full size (so `toDataURL` will generate a full-size png)  but displayed on screen at a scaled-down size.

TL;DR: Is there a way to display a 50x50 px canvas on screen, yet download a 100x100 version using `toDataURL`?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pahxjd1s/35

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is the size of the `<canvas>` element and another the size of its `bitmap`.
If you want the real size of the image to be `100x100` just set the size with `width` and `height` attributes.
Now to have the `<canvas>` element with a size of `50x50` just use CSS.

```html
<style>
.canvas {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
</style>
<canvas class="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#sizing_the_canvas_using_css_versus_html

Comment: I tried this out in my fiddle and it does not seem to work. The style applied with css appears to be ignored: https://jsfiddle.net/cbadxLvr/2/

Comment: It seems that the library forces some styles to the canvas.
You could try forcing it yourself.
https://jsfiddle.net/875u9wey/

Comment: Oh interesting, looks like this does not scale the content inside the canvas however, which is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you, but a quick way would be to apply a scale transform to the parent div.

```html
<div style={{ display: "inline-block", border: "solid", transform: `scale(${SCALE})`}}>
  <canvas
    ref={ref}
    width={100}
    height={100}
  />
</div>
```

This will also resize the control points of fabricjs and add a margin (because fabric manages the style of canvas directly). you can counter the margin by adding a `` margin: `-${100 * SCALE / 2}px` ``

I think the ideal solution would likely have a secondary canvas for the higher resolution, or generate one on demand, but this trick might be enough to get you your result.